# How to get the number/ position of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML page I have this list

```
<ul>
  <li id=a></li>
  <li id=b></li>
  <li id=c></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

How can I do in jQuery to get the "position" (meant as n-th son) of a tag knowing its id? For example something like:

```
$("#c").position() = 3
```

meant that `$("#c")` is the 3-rd child of `<ul>`. Is it possible?

Comment: or maybe .eq() works too https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: `$('li').on('click', function(){ alert($('#c').index()); })` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/778kbdn8/1/)

Comment: @RayonDabre I guess he is looking for `index+1`

Comment: @gurvinder372, You are always right!

Comment: Thanks to all guys, very very kind of yours!!

Comment: @LoryLory, Do you need to know the position of `#c`?

Comment: @FrayneKonok yes it is what I needed! thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to find the position of the element(*starts from 0*) from the set of matched elements.

Try this:

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  alert($('#c').index() + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id=a>Click here!</li>
  <li id=b>Click here!</li>
  <li id=c>Click here!</li>
</ul>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/778kbdn8/1/)

To find the position of the clicked element:

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id=a>Click here!</li>
  <li id=b>Click here!</li>
  <li id=c>Click here!</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the position of the child of the parent then you have to use the `.index()` function of jQuery.

**Example:**

*HTML:*

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    index = $(this).index();
    position = index + 1;
    alert(position);//Here is the position of child ul.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
  <li id="baz">baz</li>
</ul>

var listItem = document.getElementById( "bar" );
alert( "Index: " + $( "li" ).index( listItem ) );
```